# Pass values as parameter from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to pass values from output of select query to another query. Basically both queries will be part of a stored procedure. e.g.

```
select Id, RelId
from tables
```

There will be multiple rows returned by above query and I want to pass them to the following query

```
select name
from table2
where Id = @Id and MgId = @RelId
```

Please suggest

Comment: You can't assign multiple values to a parameter. You need a table valued parameter. Of course you could just join them and avoid transferring anything.

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass multiple values in SQL.

But maybe you can just join your 2 tables, that would be far more efficient.
Not knowing your table schemes I suggest something like this. You might have to adapt this to your actual table schemas off course

```
select name
from table2 t2
inner join tables t on t2.Id = t.Id
    and t2.MgId = t.RelId
```

**EDIT**
As Gordon mentioned in his answer, this approach can show double rows in your result.
If you don't want that than here are 2 ways of getting rid of the doubles

```
select distinct name
from ...
```

or by grouping by adding this at the end of the statement

```
group by name
```

Though this will work, avoiding the doubles like in Gordon's answer is better

Comment: Thanks Dale. It seems it will be complicated in SQL query so I am trying to write it in c#

Comment: @umesh.chape that really depends on exactly what it is you are trying to achieve. We don't have enough information to know really. But normally its quicker to wrangle all your data in SQL Server rather than pass it back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select t2.name
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from tables t
              where t2.Id = t.Id and t2.MgId = t.RelId
             );
```

The difference between `exists` and `join` is that this will not generate duplicates, if there are multiple matches between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
SELECT *
INTO #Table1
FROM ...

SELECT *
INTO #Table2
FROM ...

SELECT *
FROM #Table1 T1
JOIN #Table2 T2

DROP TABLE #Table1, #Table2
```

Comment: Why moving the data around so much ? This will not only be complicating things but also is not efficient. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it